# Delete Row in TableView using Realm

Tags: swift, realm, tableview, crud

Trying to utilize delete row feature from TableView with commit editingStyle function, but Realm seems to make this more difficult.

Function was originally created without using Realm Database and simply just an array to populate TableView. Using Realm doesn't quite work the same way though and delete function isn't working.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       if editingStyle == .delete {

           if let courseForDeletion = courses?[indexPath.row] {
               do {
                   try realm.write {
                       realm.delete(courseForDeletion)
                   }
               } catch {
                   print("Error deleting course: \(error)")
               }

               tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
           }
       }
   }
```

Expecting swipe gesture on given row to generate red delete feature that typically happens when not using Realm.

Comment: Unrelated but **never ever** call `reloadData()` right after `insertRows/deleteRows`. The `insert/delete` methods update the UI animated.

Comment: @vadian thanks for the insight - regardless, any ideas on why this method doesn't reproduce same functionality as soon as Realm is introduced?

Comment: No, the method is supposed to work. Is `canEditRowAt` implemented to return `false`? However the `deleteRows` line must be inside the `if let` scope. And why is `courses` optional? Is the table view optional, too?

Comment: @vadian `canEditRowAt` is currently implemented to return `true` , I pushed `deleteRows` up into the `if let` scope and it still isn't responding with a swipe gesture. The `courses` object is optional because initially the table contains none and the user can generate them via an `addCourses` bar button item which prompts a UIAlert

Comment: Once again, the code should work with `canEditRowAt` returning `true` (which is the default by the way). *...the table contains none* can also be represented by a **non-optional empty** array and you get rid of all optional bindings.

Comment: @vadian Very true, I may go back and edit the code after all functionality works to remove optional binding used in multiple areas, but don't think that's the culprit for why this swipe gesture isn't recognizing

Comment: Yes, the optional array does not cause the swipe gesture issue.

Comment: @vadian I have also tried using `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`, but my understanding is that if I'm looking for just a delete function the `commitEditingStyle` using the `.destructive` option is simpler

Comment: If the standard implementation works then `trailingSwipeActions` works, too. And vice versa.

Comment: @vadian figured it out - problem was that the Cell itself was still inheriting from a custom class that was from a SwipeCellKit CocoaPod that I was getting away from using

Answer (score -1):

What makes you think the delete function is not working?

To see the row get deleted, you need to call tableview.reloadData()

Comment: *you need to call tableview.reloadData()*. No, you don't. `deleteRows` does update the table view